# Find all $n$ such that each number containing $n$ $1$'s and one $3$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This question is [O205](http://awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2011_6/MR5solutions.pdf#page=20) from the [Mathematical Reflections](http://awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/).
I do not own any copyrights to this question.

> Find all $n$ such that each number containing $n$ $1$'s and one $3$ is prime.

For example, when $n=2$ we find that $113, 131$ and $311$ are prime.

Comment: Clearly $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: There is a test for the divisibility by 7 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7, second §) which rules out any $n \geq 6$.

Comment: @D.Thomine Could you elaborate?

Comment: @D. Thomine That seems to rule out only those $n$ greater than $4$ which are not congruent to $5$ mod $6$.

Comment: @ Chris. You are right. I found my mistake.

Comment: And 17 rules out $n \geq 9, n \not= 15 \pmod{16}$, 19 rules out $n \geq 11, n \not= 17 \pmod{18}$ and 23 rules out $n \geq 17, n \not= 21 \pmod{22}$ from the limited experimental evidence I have (I could be wrong though)

Answer (score 3):

Any such $n$ gives a $(n+1)$-digit ["permutable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutable_prime) or ["absolute" prime](http://oeis.org/A003459).
Clearly $n=0,1,2$ work, and it's conjectured that there are no absolute primes other than repunits larger than 991.

As hinted by @Sp3000, if 10 is a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) mod a prime $p$ then if $n>p$ then $p-1$ must divide $n+1$. According to [this paper by Slinko](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/OEIS/archive_in_pdf/Absolute_Primes.pdf), by considering all such primes up to $10^5$ Richert came up with a lower bound on the number of digits $>6\times 10^{175}$.  The paper details which forms of numbers cannot be permutable primes, but notably multiple 1s and a single 3 is one of the few forms that remains as a possibility, implying that this case is still open.

Related, [this article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3618302) attributes the problem with several 1s and one 7 to Slinko and notes it as considered for the IMO. That version is resolved by Theorem 3 in the paper I cited above.

Answer (score 2):

$1...31 \ - \ 1...13=18\\
1...311 \ - \ 1...131=180\\
1...3111 \ - \ 1...1311=1800$

If $1...113\equiv x \mod 17$ then $1...131\equiv x+18 \mod 17\equiv x+1 \mod17$ and $1...311\equiv x+18+180 \mod 17\equiv x+11 \mod17$.

The first 50 terms in this sequence contain every possible residue$\mod 17$ therefore if none of the permutations is a multiple of $17$ then $n\leq 50$. I checked all $n$ up to $50$ and the only solutions I found were $0,1,2$.

Comment: If $n=95$, none of the $96$ integers with $95$ ones and one three are divisible by $17$. In fact, this happens for every $n\equiv47\pmod{48}$.